# How can I fail a build if any java file is detected with System.out.println in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, static-analysis

I am using `Jenkins` as our build tool. I don't want `System.out.println` to be there in the code. Is there a way by which we can add a hook which will check this. And if any `.java` file is detected with `System.out.println` then fail the build.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static code analysis tool. For example PMD (https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.3.3/index.html) .

You can specify a rule that checks for calls to `System.out.println`. 
How to write a rule: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.3.3/customizing/howtowritearule.html

You can analyze your code with PMD over Jenkins via the PMD plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PMD+Plugin

There are some good tutorials for using PMD with Jenkins. A good one is this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRgYd-SLyrs

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. Is there any way I can achieve this using Shell Script option in Jenkins configuration. Because, for configuring PMD I will have contact our business admin and that might take a long time for approval and all.

Comment: When considering the use of an open source tool takes much time then you're going to run into deep problems sooner or later. Of course you can write a shell script that searches for the string 'System.out.println' in all `.java` files but you won't be happy for a long time. If there is an occurence like this 'System<LINEBREAK>.out<LINEBREAK>.println' then your solution won't probably find it. I recommend not to do the file search on your own. There are really good (and free!) tools out there. Use them! They do the work much better then you could ever do it as a part of a side project.

Comment: i understand the point you are making. I have raised request to add he rule in pmd now. I hope i will hear soon from my client. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "Jenkins-ize" this, set up Jenkins to run with Sonar, and add a rule in Sonar that fails if System.out.println is found.

Advantages:
- you can run nightly sonar builds
- you can add more than that one rule (and you should ;))
- you will check code on the whole branch, not just yours.